# Installation - on/off at check-out

Tags: checkout, orders

Is it possible to let my customers to choose if they want installation
yes / no at check-out.

**I made it like this:**

- All orders under ex. 2000,- cost 150 in delivery.
- orders over 2000,- are free.

However, the installation should always cost ex. 200

It is designed so that the customer must decide whether they want installation or not. (customers just need to be able to select it)

How is that possible?
(I am using flatrate rules to control my delivery amount)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the extension like

"add gift message"

and/or

"add extra fees"

some of them allow to add paid options into the checkout page.

Comment: Hi there Giuseppe

Super thanks for your reply. Super good idear.
I´ll try it out.

C yaa | Cheers
Kimo